# Android: In-app billing question

Tags: android, billing, in-app

I have a question regarding in-app billing. I have a published app that currently offers a single in-app product. If I plan to add another in-app product, do I have to push an update? Assume that I fetch the list of products to display to the user from a private server.

Thanks,

Akshay

P.S: This is a hypothetical scenario, which is why I can't try it myself using a publisher account.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, your application only needs to know the product's name to send the billing request, so I think there is no need to update your app on the market, if you have an option to fetch the product names from the server. It's just an assumption, haven't tried it myself.

Comment: Thanks Egor! That's my assumption too and it makes sense logically. But I want to be sure about it & expect someone who has tried this to answer.

Comment: Agree it will work. Provided you send the correct productId in your BillingRequest.